# Server command?

Tags: server

Hi all I've got a couple of questions.  I was asked to log into an online server and I have to figure out these questions:

- Find the command that will show you the month of your birthday in the year 2024 (ten years into the future).
- A cataclysm happened in September 1752.  Find the command that will show you the calendar for the entire year 1752 so that we can check on September.
- Find out what kind of CPU is in the server.

I'm having a hard time figuring out the commands for these.  All help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: We do not do your homework on askubuntu ;)

Comment: i'm pretty sure my birthday occurs in the same month every year... ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind could be an interesting pub quiz, too.

Comment: No worries thought id get some direction is all :)

Answer (score 3):

Since it would seem to be homework, I'll give some strong hints instead of the exact commands; I assume you know how to look at manual pages.

`cal` is a useful command, and `/proc/cpuinfo` would seem to be an interesting file to have a look at.